# Button onclick functions only if form is validated

Tags: c#, jquery, html, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a form in a partial view, I want 2 functions to happen when a button in clicked but only if the form in validated. When i add the the onclick functions to the button the form no longer validates. Can I set if(valid) in the button. can this be done? What I want is only call the fuctions if the form is validated.

```
              <input type="submit" value="Create" id="btnclick"  onclick="CreateMech(); createUser(document.getElementById('username').value, document.getElementById('password').value)"   class="btn-danger"  />
```

Comment: Call a function that check the form validity and then calls CreatMech() and createUser() if valid

Answer (score 0):

you can use prevent default to stop the click if validation fails.  something like

```
$(document).on('click', '#btnclick', function(e){
    if("validation check function here" == false){
        e.preventDefault();
        alert("validation failed);
    }else{
        CreateMech(); //adding the else here will make the on click on your button unnecessary
    }
});
```

should work for you